# querying facts meeting a clips condition

Tags: clips

```
(deffunction query (?templ $?filters)
   (do-for-all-facts ((?fi ?templ)) (eq (fact-slot-value ?fi (nth$ 1 $?filters)) (nth$ 2 $?filters)) (ppfact ?fi) ) )
```

Using the above function I can query/list facts of passed template name `?templ` that satisfies passed `$?filters` which is a sequence of slotname slot value pairs; eg:

```
(query vlanStatus vlan 100 intf "eth12") will print all facts of vlanStatus with valn 100 and intf "eth12".
```

I am trying to generalize it to specify the filter to be any clips condition construct. Is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the query (query vlanStatus vlan 100 intf "eth12") will not work as the function does not go beyond 2nd slot of multi-field arg.  (query vlanStatus vlan 100 ) will work.

Want to generalize this to specify a filter as a generic clips condition so that the above limitations are overcome and further filter becomes generic.

Answer (score 0):

```
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate vlanStatus
   (slot vlan)
   (slot intf)
   (slot info))
CLIPS>      
(deffacts testing
   (vlanStatus (vlan 100) (intf "eth32") (info 3)) 
   (vlanStatus (vlan 100) (intf "eth12") (info 4)) 
   (vlanStatus (vlan 200) (intf "eth33") (info 5)) 
   (vlanStatus (vlan 200) (intf "eth33") (info 6)) 
   (vlanStatus (vlan 100) (intf "eth12") (info 7))) 
CLIPS> 
(deffunction apply-filters (?fact ?filters)
   (loop-for-count (?i 1 (div (length$ ?filters) 3))
      (bind ?base (* (- ?i 1) 3))
      (if (not (funcall (nth$ (+ ?base 1) ?filters)
                        (fact-slot-value ?fact (nth$ (+ ?base 2) ?filters))
                        (nth$ (+ ?base 3) ?filters)))
         then
         (return FALSE)))
   (return TRUE))
CLIPS> 
(deffunction query (?templ $?filters)
   (if (!= (mod (length$ ?filters) 3) 0)
      then
      (printout t "Function query expected the filter list to be a multiple of 3." crlf)
      (return FALSE))
   (do-for-all-facts ((?fi ?templ)) 
      (apply-filters ?fi ?filters)
      (ppfact ?fi)))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (query vlanStatus eq vlan 100 eq intf "eth12")
(vlanStatus 
   (vlan 100) 
   (intf "eth12") 
   (info 4))
(vlanStatus 
   (vlan 100) 
   (intf "eth12") 
   (info 7))
CLIPS> (query vlanStatus eq vlan 100 <= info 6)
(vlanStatus 
   (vlan 100) 
   (intf "eth32") 
   (info 3))
(vlanStatus 
   (vlan 100) 
   (intf "eth12") 
   (info 4))
CLIPS>
```